# How to render RDLC report in Sharepoint 2013 Report Viewer WebPart?

Tags: development, reports

How can I render a `rdlc` report into webpart in sharepoint 2013. I have created a report, also added a data-source and a dataset. I have the following code:

```
           ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
           ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

           if (dynGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dynGridView.DataSourceObject);
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
           }
```

and I am getting this error: [image]

my datasource looks like this:
[image]

please help me.

Comment: where's the code that should fill dynGridView? what's the data source of it?